# ¿Como detener un audio desde un activity distinto al de inicio?

Tags: audio, mediaplayer

ante todo felicidades y gracias de antemano por la gran ayuda que recibo de este foro de hilos ya resueltos.

Tengo una canción que se ejecuta desde el Oncreate del Activity principal
Así:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        musica=MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,R.raw.magia);

  musica.start();
//
}
```

---

Empieza la música automáticamente cuando comienza la app.

cuando cambio de activity, no cierro la principal , main.

Cuando desde la ultima pantalla (Activity) intento cerrar con

musica.stop();

No funciona, al salir de la aplicación sigue sonando y cuando le doy atrás (triangulíto)con el botón del móvil al volver a la main_Activity , vuelve a empezar la música y se solapa con la ya empezada( me conformo con que se detenga con un onClick(View v) desde un boton.)
He mirado cosas como el método Ondestroy, pero no lo entiendo bien.

Me podrían ayudar.
Agradecería explicaciones muy detallada pues soy muy novato en Android Studio.( Aunque he programado en las sheet de google con java y conozco visual basic, pero la dinámica de android studio no la conozco bien.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Saludos.

Comment: Has intentado hacerlo con clases con atributos estaticos?  Te creas una clase con atributos estático de tipo "MediaPlayer", algo así:  class MiMusica{  static MediaPlayer musica;   }  y luego desde cualquier parte del código utilizas: MiMusica.musica.top; para detenerla, no olvides importar la clase MiMusica  en donde quiera mandar a detenerla y tambien el paquete MediaPlayer

Comment: Te recomiendo que revises la documentación del ciclo de vida de una [Activity](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle). Cuando sales de una Activity, se ejecutan ciertas funciones dependiendo de lo que haga el sistema con tu activity. `onPause()`, `onStop()`, `onDestroy()`. Hasta que el sistema no decide eliminar tu Activity, no se llama a `onDestroy()`. Así que tendrás que estudiar dónde inicias y detienes la reproducción del audio en función de lo que quieras que pase.

Comment: Gracias a los dos.                                                                                   
Santiago esta es mi segunda aplicación, no se que muy bien que es una clase , ni los atributos estáticos, pero lo voy a estudiar.                                                   SuperG280 , conozco mas o menos el ciclo de vida, pero no estos métodos que pones, también los mirare. Gracias de nuevo por la pronta y concisa respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Tengo el mismo problema. Ademas de cuando se gira el celular se crea otra instancia y se vuelve a reiniciar la musica superponiedose con la anterior. Y cuando se sale de la aplicación esta sigue corriendo. En una cree una variable que se incrementaba cada vez que se recreaba la aplicación y con eso logre, junto con un if, que no se creen mas instancias pero no solucionaba el problema de salir